# Play Billing Library Version Deprecation Issues

Tags: codenameone

I got warning messages from Google Play console after sending my CN1 Android built for publishing my Android app.

> We've detected that this app is using an old version of Google Play Billing. From November 1, 2023, all app updates must use Billing Library version 5 or newer.
>
> Action required: Please verify your publicly available APKs are updated to the latest version of the Play Billing Library. This includes any APK or App Bundle rolled out in production.

Comment: I suggest filing an issue similar to [this one](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3404).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a Play Store related issue that should be discussed with Google support. The [help/on-topic] says specifically that this sort of question is off-topic here. In addition, the email tells you exactly what is required, so there's nothing anyone here can add, and you have not asked a question of any sort.

Comment: This question is for codename one.

Comment: Hi Shai, How is the status of this Google Play Billing issue?
Is the issue related to the server side?

Comment: Hi Shai, please notice this announcement 
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/deprecation-faq

1. Starting on August 2, 2023, all new apps must use Billing Library version 5 or newer. By November 1, 2023, all updates to existing apps must use Billing Library version 5 or newer. Learn more.

Comment: This is pending as we are dealing with a file system issue on Android 13 which currently takes precedence.

Comment: Hi Shai, would you let me know when you will solve this Google Play Billing issue?
Thank you.

Comment: Is there an issue? If there is one and it's assigned it usually gets resolved when we're done. Steve had a couple of things in his queue before he could address that so I'm not sure if he started yet.

Comment: Yes, I already filed an issue on June 3. https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3706

Comment: I'll post there and try to get a higher priority for this.